# Convert char aray to a floting point value

Tags: c++, file, char

so I have some code that looks a little like this where the file "float" is a file with a float value

```c
FILE* f;
float a;
f = fopen("float", "rb");
char buffer[sizeof(float)];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f) == NULL) break;
```

so how would i convert the information from buffer to a?

Comment: Note that `sizeof(float)` is typically 4, so only upto 2 digits will be accepted. (the rest 2 elements are for newline character and terminating null-character)

Comment: When you say "a file with a float value", do you mean the file contains a string of ASCII characters that represents a float, or that the bytes in the file themselves constitute an IEEE 754 float?

Comment: If the file actually contains a binary `float`, use `fread()` instead of `fgets()`, and know that you can actually get rid of the `buffer` altogether and just read directly into `a` instead, eg: `float a; if (fgets(&a, sizeof a, 1, f) != 1) { ... } ... fclose(f);`

Comment: BTW, this code looks more C than C++, are you sure you have the question tagged correctly?

Comment: yes, the code is in c++ and the "float" file carries a text representation of the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`strtof()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof) from the header `cstdlib`.

```
char* end;
a = strtof(buffer, &end);
if (*end != '\0' && *end != '\n') {
    /* handle error : invalid character exists */
}
```

Comment: This solution assumes the file contains a text representation of a floating-point value. The fact that the OP's code is opening the file in binary mode, and allocating a buffer just large enough to hold a binary `float`, suggests that may not actually be the case. Though the use of `fgets()` puts doubt on that...